# dpkg: error processing package, Could not install any package

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, dpkg, dependencies

I am new to Ubuntu. And I am using 14.04.

Whenever i try to install any software i get an error with dpkg. After  browsing for some time, i get some commands to try out.
 Nothing really helped. The first one is to run, **sudo dpkg --configure -a**

But this is all I get when I run that,

> ```
> dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
>  package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
>  reinstall it before attempting configuration
> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-gtk:
>  software-properties-gtk depends on software-properties-common; however:
>   Package software-properties-common is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package software-properties-gtk (--configure):
>  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
> Errors were encountered while processing:
>  software-properties-common
>  software-properties-gtk
> ```

When I tried the next command, `sudo apt-get install -f`
I get this..,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,370 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-gtk:
 software-properties-gtk depends on software-properties-common; however:
  Package software-properties-common is not configured yet.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 software-properties-common
 software-properties-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

FYI, don't have synaptic installed

**Any Help is greatly appreciated.. Thanks..**

Comment: Try a `sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-properties-common` and give me a ping with `@A.B.` in the comments.

Comment: If that does not help, you might try to `sudo apt-get purge software-properties-gtk software-properties-common` followed by `sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk software-properties-common`.

Comment: sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-properties-common worked!! I also did reinstall  software-properties-gtk.. Everything is fine now.. Thanks @A.B. ; Byte Commander

Comment: I have converted the content to an answer. Do you have any idea how it came to your problem? I am just curious.

Comment: Sorry A.B. I Have no idea how do I get into this situation :(  @A.B. I just came to know when auto-update failed updating the installed packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the idea in the comment works, here is the answer:

1. To remove an eventually corrupted DEB package

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```
2. Force the reinstall of the corrupted package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-properties-common
   ```

   Because that's only a reinstall of a package, no other packages will revive.

Comment: Hope you are doing good.
I've been confronting an issue while installin .deb package on debian machine. i have tried various way but not able to install it.If i use "sudo dpkg -i  HM_snowagent_6.0.0-1_amd64.deb" . it doesn't work and "sudo apt-get install" doesn't work for me. Please advise